# DB2: Split a general result-string in columns by delimiter

Tags: db2

In DB2 I have one result-string, e.g. like

```
Color|Product|Category|Price|...
```

Now I like to generate four (or n) columns containing each string-token split by the pipe

```
Col1      Col2     Col3     Col4     Col...
Color     Product  Category Price    ...
```

I am looking for a general solution with arbitrarily number of cols.

The use of this result is to use it in a UNION with another SELECT-Query.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Where do you want to present this output? via the DB2CLP ou another program.

If you want to retrieve the values in another program, it depends how the program manage the output, and you just put tabulation when scanning the output.

For example, for Java

```
System.out.println(col1+"\t"+col2+"\t"+col3);
```

On the other side, if you want to retrieve the values in DB2CLP or a similar shell, an your string is retrieved from the database with these pipes, you should created a scalar function to process the field before returning it to the user.

You will need functions like

- Length http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000818.html
- Concat http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000781.html or ||
- Posstr http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000835.html

The best way is to create a recursive function, that iterates for each token. The basic case is when the string is empty or the string does not finish by a pipe. The recursive case is when the string has pipe.

The process is to read the characters (into a variable) until the first pipe. If a pipe is detected, the quantity of spaces to simulate a tab are added, and then the same function is called with the trailing string.

You should pass the string to read, and the already processed string.

The Function could be like this

**function.sql**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MODULE TEST@
ALTER MODULE TEST PUBLISH
  FUNCTION PROCESS (
  STRING varchar(255),
  NEW_STRING varchar(255)
) RETURNS varchar(255)
@

ALTER MODULE TEST ADD
  FUNCTION PROCESS (
  STRING varchar(255),
  NEW_STRING varchar(255)
) RETURNS varchar(255)
PROC: begin
  DECLARE IND INT;
  DECLARE LEN INT;
  DECLARE MODU INT;
  DECLARE CHARS INT;
  DECLARE TAB INT DEFAULT 8;
  DECLARE PRE VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE POS VARCHAR(255);

  SET IND = POSSTR(STRING, '|');
  IF (IND <> 0) THEN
    SET PRE = SUBSTR(STRING, 1, IND - 1);
    SET POS = SUBSTR(STRING, IND + 1);

    SET NEW_STRING = TEST.PROCESS (POS, NEW_STRING);

    SET PRE = TRIM(PRE);
    SET LEN = LENGTH(PRE);
    SET MODU = MOD(LEN, TAB);
    IF (MODU <> 0) THEN
      SET CHARS = TAB - MODU;
      WHILE (CHARS <> TAB) DO
        SET PRE = CONCAT (PRE, ' ');
        SET CHARS = CHARS + 1;
      END WHILE;
    END IF;
  ELSE
    SET PRE = STRING;
  END IF;

  RETURN CONCAT (PRE, COALESCE(NEW_STRING,''));

end PROC@
```

Compilation and execution

```
db2 -td@ -f function.sql ; db2 "values test.process('Color|Product|Category|Price|...','')"

1
-----------------------------------------
Color     Product       CategoryPrice     ...
  1 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I like to Export a DB2 table as csv by batch-file and need to export the column headers. Since they might change (order of cols, names) I Need to retrive them from the syscat.columns. Now I am looking for a way to export header and data in one single command so I dont have to copy header and data in one file after the export (double space-requirement on disk) .